# do not display scientific numbers axis dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.style

  
data = {'V': [116302,797183,1736044,311815,83692,131565],
        'O': [59019,381176,896383,168083,41923,77694],
        'I': [57283,416007,839661,143732,41769,53871]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['V','O','I'], index = ['1550','1600','1650','1700','1750','1800'])

plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
df.plot.barh()

#print
plt.show()
```

I would like to remove the scientific values below, and display them in full, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Save your plot in a variable and use `.ticklabel_format` with `style="plain"`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.style

  
data = {'V': [116302,797183,1736044,311815,83692,131565],
        'O': [59019,381176,896383,168083,41923,77694],
        'I': [57283,416007,839661,143732,41769,53871]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['V','O','I'], index = ['1550','1600','1650','1700','1750','1800'])

plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
pl = df.plot.barh()
pl.ticklabel_format(axis="x", style="plain")

#print
plt.show()
```

[image]